# Chinese text rendering strangely after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, chinese

I just upgraded to 12.04 and it's had a very strange effect on the way Chinese text displays on my system. In both Chrome and gedit, text that would have displayed normally in 11.10 seems to be rendered in a combination of two fonts: one "normal" font and one that seems lighter and italicized. It's very annoying and difficult to read; any idea what could have caused this? I made no changes to my system besides upgrading to Precise Pangolin.

Comment: Could be a bad default if trying to render glyphs as Japanese before falling back to a Chinese font, or something similar.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. any idea how to change it back to a Chinese default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at what fonts are available for a certain language (such as Chinese "zh") by running `fc-list :lang=zh`.

Try first installing any other Chinese fonts that you might want and then manually rebuild the font cache by running `fc-cache -f`.

You can manually set the order of fonts by editing your `~/.fonts.conf`. Here is one example I found from the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=812552) for prioritizing Japanese:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fontconfig>
 <alias>
 <family>serif</family>
 <prefer>
 <family>DejaVu Serif</family>
 <family>Times New Roman</family>
 <family>ＭＳ 明朝</family>
 <family>IPAPMincho</family>
 <family>Sazanami Mincho</family>
 <family>Kochi Mincho</family>
 <family>Bitstream Vera Serif</family>
 <family>Thorndale AMT</family>
 <family>Luxi Serif</family>
 <family>Nimbus Roman No9 L</family>
 <family>Times</family>
 <family>Frank Ruehl</family>
 <family>MgOpen Canonica</family>
 <family>AR PL SungtiL GB</family>
 <family>AR PL Mingti2L Big5</family>
 <family>FreeSerif</family>
 <family>Baekmuk Batang</family>
 </prefer>
 </alias>
 <alias>
 <family>sans-serif</family>
 <prefer>
 <family>DejaVu Sans</family>
 <family>Verdana</family>
 <family>ＭＳ ゴシック</family>
 <family>IPAPGothic</family>
 <family>Sazanami Gothic</family>
 <family>Kochi Gothic</family>
 <family>Bitstream Vera Sans</family>
 <family>Arial</family>
 <family>Albany AMT</family>
 <family>Luxi Sans</family>
 <family>Nimbus Sans L</family>
 <family>Helvetica</family>
 <family>Nachlieli</family>
 <family>MgOpen Moderna</family>
 <family>AR PL KaitiM GB</family>
 <family>AR PL KaitiM Big5</family>
 <family>FreeSans</family>
 <family>Baekmuk Dotum</family>
 <family>SimSun</family>
 </prefer>
 </alias>
 <alias>
 <family>monospace</family>
 <prefer>
 <family>DejaVu Sans Mono</family>
 <family>Courier New</family>
 <family>ＭＳ ゴシック</family>
 <family>IPAGothic</family>
 <family>Sazanami Gothic</family>
 <family>Kochi Gothic</family>
 <family>Bitstream Vera Sans Mono</family>
 <family>Andale Mono</family>
 <family>Cumberland AMT</family>
 <family>Luxi Mono</family>
 <family>Nimbus Mono L</family>
 <family>Courier</family>
 <family>Miriam Mono</family>
 <family>FreeMono</family>
 <family>AR PL KaitiM GB</family>
 <family>Baekmuk Dotum</family>
 </prefer>
 </alias>
 <match target="font" >
 <edit mode="assign" name="embeddedbitmap" >
 <bool>true</bool>
 </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Note that I haven't actually tried this yet.